Problem E1 in Engels's "Problem Solving Strategies"
I am trying to solve problem E1 in Engels's book on the invariance principle. He includes a write-up of a solution, but it seems to me to be missing details. I'll paraphrase what he wrote.
The setup is: we start with a point $S = (a,b)$ with $0 < b < a$ and generate a sequence recursively by
$$
x_0 = a, \quad y_0 = b, \quad x_{n+1} = \frac{x_n + y_n}{2}, \quad y_{n+1} = \frac{2x_n y_n}{x_n + y_n}. 
$$
He notices the invariant that
$$
x_{n+1} y_{n+1} = \left(\frac{x_n + y_n}{2} \right)\left(y_{n+1} = \frac{2x_n y_n}{x_n + y_n} \right)= x_n y_n. 
$$
So $x_1 y_1 = x_0 y_0 = ab$, and by induction, $x_n y_n = ab$ for all $n$. Then that $y_n < x_n$ for every $n$ follows from induction and the relationship between the arithmetic and harmonic mean. The next line, which I can follow algebraically, is:
$$
0 < x_{n+1} - y_{n+1} = \frac{x_n - y_n}{x_n + y_n} \cdot \frac{x_n - y_n}{2} <  \frac{x_n - y_n}{2}.
$$
The equality is just algebra, and the second line states that $x_n + y_n > x_n - y_n$ because $x_n, y_n > 0$. He then says:

So we have $\lim x_n = \lim y_n = x$ with $x^2 = ab$ or $x = \sqrt{ab}$.

I don't understand why $x_n$ and $y_n$ must converge and why the limits are equal. I'm not sure whether he is using the squeeze theorem somewhere. The difference between $x_{n+1}$ and $y_{n+1}$ gets smaller as $n$ grows because it's less than half the difference between the previous $x$ and $y$ coordinates. It's also always positive. But I don't understand why it must go to $0$. The constant sequence of $0$'s certainly converges to $0$, but why must the sequence $\frac{x_n - y_n}{2}$ converge to $0$?

For your last question that the difference converges to $0$, using your inequality, $0<x_n-y_n < (a-b)2^{-n}$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty} (a-b)2^{-n} = 0$.

$x_n$ must converge, because $0<y_n < x_{n+1} < x_n$ -- the sequence $(x_n)$ is decreasing and bounded below.


The difference between $x_{n + 1}$ and $y_{n + 1}$ gets smaller as $n$ grows because it's less than half the difference between the previous $x$ and $y$ coordinates.

This is the key. In general, just having that $d (x_{n + 1}, y_{n + 1}) < d (x_n, y_n)$ indeed does not imply that $(d (x_n, y_n)) \to 0$. There are some pretty simple examples of this that you could construct.
However, if there is some number $\alpha < 1$ such that $d (x_{n + 1}, y_{n + 1}) \le \alpha d (x_n, y_n)$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, then it is guaranteed that $(d (x_n, y_n)) \to 0$. To show that this is the case, let $\varepsilon > 0$ be arbitrary. If $d (x_0, y_0) < \varepsilon$ or $\alpha = 0$, take $N = 0$; otherwise, take $N = \left\lceil \frac{\ln \varepsilon - \ln d (x_0, y_0)}{\ln \alpha} \right\rceil$. Then for any $n > N$, we have
$$d (x_n, y_n) \le \alpha^n d (x_0, y_0) < \alpha^N d (x_0, y_0) \le \left( \frac{\varepsilon}{d (x_0, y_0)} \right) d (x_0, y_0) = \varepsilon$$
In your case, you showed that the given sequence $x_n, y_n$ has $\alpha = \frac{1}{2} < 1$, so you have $(d (x_n, y_n)) \to 0$.

Thank you, this is very helpful. I have a quick follow-up question after working more on this. This proof above shows that $(|x_n - y_n|)$ converges to $0$. But the fact alone doesn't guarantee that $\lim x_n = \lim y_n$, e.g., one of the sequences could fail to converge. Can I say that $(x_n)$ is decreasing and bounded below, so it converges, so this fact that implies that $(y_n)$ converges?

Yes, if you know that $(|y_n - x_n|)$ converges to $0$ and $(x_n)$ converges to $L$, then $(y_n)$ converges to $L$. You can prove it as follows. Let $\varepsilon > 0$ be arbitrary. Select $N_1$ such that $|x_n - L| < \frac{1}{2} \varepsilon$ for all $n > N_1$. Select $N_2$ such that $|y_n - x_n| < \frac{1}{2} \varepsilon$ for all $n > N_2$. Then for all $n > \max{N_1, N_2}$, $|y_n - L| \le |y_n - x_n| + |x_n - L| < \frac{1}{2} \varepsilon + \frac{1}{2} \varepsilon = \varepsilon$, as desired.
